# Can I use maths equations in Grafana Graph Metrics?

Tags: grafana, influxdb

My situation:-

I'm measuring the level in my rain water tanks using a float on an arm, connected to a variable potentiometer, monitored by an Arduino.
As the tank goes down the voltage reading decreases in a sinusoidal way (for a range of pi/2 radians, i.e 90 degrees).

Currently I'm reading the values from an InfluxDB remotely via Grafana, which is just displaying the voltage level. This reading will become more and more inaccurate as the level goes down due to the change in angle as it gets lower.

To fix this I want to add a sin(theta) equation into the Grafana/Graph/Metrics section. But I can not find out if that is possible to do that.
From what I've found it appears it may be beyond Grafana to do that, but I've got my fingers crossed as the only other options will be to try and add something into the InfuxDB (way beyond my knowledge) or add the code directly onto the Arduino, which by the way it's all mounted and attached inside my rain water tanks, is something I'm not keen to do.

If anyone can let me know if it's possible (or not) to do it via Grafana it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks you.

Comment: You can do some math on the InfluxDB query level - https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/functions/

Comment: That looks like I'll need to do that in the DB itself then send out the new values to Grafana. Bit more complex than I hoped :(, but at least it's an option :), thank you.

Comment: InfluxDB calculation is better than calculating in the browser (in Grafana), which may kill Grafana performance in the case of a huge dataset or complex math. If you need only single value calculation (one datapoint calculation), then you can  use singlestat math panel. But it is not a good idea for the graphs = many datapoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q:** Can I use maths equations in Grafana Graph Metrics?

**A:** Short answer **no**. Grafana is a data visualisation tool for making sense out of a dataset.

The job of a `timeseries` panel like `Graph` is to take in a set of timeseries dataset formatted as below, and plot the data point accordingly.

**Example dataset:**

```
[
  {
    "target":"upper_75", // The field being queried for
    "datapoints":[
      [622,1450754160000],  // Metric value as a float , unixtimestamp in milliseconds
      [365,1450754220000]
    ]
  },
  {
    "target":"upper_90",
    "datapoints":[
      [861,1450754160000],
      [767,1450754220000]
    ]
  }
]
```

`InfluxDb` do support the `Sin` mathematical operation but I am not sure whether is that sufficient to you or not. I failed my maths in high school so I'm not sure if `sin(theta) == sin()` or not.

If the `influxdb` datasource UI does not support the `SIN` operation yet,  you can actually toggle the "advance query edition" mode to manually build it. See img below.

Also, you can learn more about the influx Mathematical syntax [here](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/functions/#sin).

[image]

**References:**

https://github.com/grafana/simple-json-datasource

https://play.grafana.org/d/Zzlfq17mk/influx-table-merge?panelId=2&fullscreen&edit&orgId=1

https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/functions/#sin

Comment: Thanks for the answer and information. I'll investigate the influxDB select call you show in the image. Also, yes sin(theta) is basically sin(), the theta just represents the angle you wish to get the sin of.

Comment: For some reason the version of Grafana running on my Pine64 is the latest and doesn't have a visible way to access the advanced option you show in the picture and References, I think it's version 2.6.0.

Comment: `2.6.0` is quite old. The `UI` is definitely going to be very different. Probably can try upgrading to the latest `arm` release at https://grafana.com/grafana/download?platform=arm

Comment: Thanks for the link and suggestion, very helpful. It was a little bit tricky to get it to upgrade on the Pine64, so I'll just explain what I did in case someone needs to know. I downloaded the Debian ARM64 version from the link you gave, did a "sudo apt-get remove grafana" and also had to do a "sudo apt-get remove grafana-data". If you don't the install fails. Then I finally ran "sudo dpkg -i grafana_5.4.3_arm64.deb". then just refreshed the Dashboard. Thankfully it remembered it :)